# Phone connected to wireless but does not respond to pings

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-2, networking, vanilla-android, samsung-galaxy-mini

I have here two phones that both exhibit the same symptoms.  One is a samsung GT-S5570 running the stock ROM, the other is a Galaxy S2 running an AOSP-based custom ROM.  The problem I have is that while they are connected to the wifi and are able to browse web sites, etc, they periodically stop accepting incoming connections and/or responding to pings.  In order to get them to start responding again I have to disconnect and reconnect the wireless connection.  Yet they are still able to make outbound connections.

Any ideas what may be causing this (somewhat bizarre) behaviour or how I can stop it?

Comment: Are you trying to ping your phones from some other devices connected to same wifi network?

Comment: Yes.  Fortunately, I believe I may have found the cause to the problem -- there were two DHCP servers on the network which were handing out potentially-conflicting IP addresses.  I think this may have been causing my router to get confused over which devices were connected wirelessly or over the wired connection, and it must have been attempting to switch the packets intelligently.  At least, on removing the extra DHCP server the problem went away; the rest is just my only working theory as to how this could happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my comment above; appears to have been caused by a broken DHCP configuration.